# No shown files and right-click

Tags: unity, gnome

I've installed Gnome desktop besides Unity. It was very unstable system, therefore, I removed Gnome but it was not completely removed.

Now, welcome icon of Gnome is shown. No files shown on desktop and right-click on unity desktop .
How I can I fix this?

Comment: Hi , Mohsen. We will need a little more clarification. What do you mean by `Weclome icon of Gnome` ? Can you give us a screenshot ? Second, can you please open the terminal and run this command : `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons` . Command 2:  we need to know what it says.

Comment: Also, how did you install Gnome ? Was it `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop` ?

Comment: Hi.Welcome icone means load icone of Gnome before show lightdm.
Result of command is False.
Yes I inastall ubuntu-gnome-desktop

Comment: You can use `sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell-*` to remove gnome shell completely.

Comment: @MohsenParsaeian very well, and what does the `gsettings` command tell ?

Comment: Result of  command is False.

Comment: Good ! Writing an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call `Gnome welcome icon` is actually called plymouth. You can change its settings via `update-alternatives` command. Here is my example:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth 
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
There are 3 choices for the alternative default.plymouth (providing /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth).

  Selection    Path                                                                   Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntukylin-logo/ubuntukylin-logo.plymouth   150       auto mode
  1            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo-scale-2.plymouth     99        manual mode
  2            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth             100       manual mode
  3            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntukylin-logo/ubuntukylin-logo.plymouth   150       manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

If I wanted to change to some other setting, i would press for example 3 and enter.

As for desktop, run this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```